# How to create a Keras model using a frozen_interference_graph.pb?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, image-segmentation, deeplab

I want to use a pre-trained model and add a segmentation head at the end of that, but the problem is that I just have the '*frozen_inference_graph.pb*'. These are the files that I have from the model:

[image]

I have tried several ways:

**1. loading the pre-trained model into a Keras model:**
It seems to be impossible with the files that I have. It just gives me an AutoTrackable object instead of a model.

**2. Accessing the Tensor Objects of the frozen model and make the model with tensors:**
I found out how to access the tensors but couldn't make a Keras model with Tensor objects.

```
with self.graph.as_default():
    graph = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

graph = tf.compat.v1.import_graph_def(graph_def)
tf.compat.v1.Graph.as_default(graph)
self.sess = tf.Session(graph=self.graph)
self.tensors = [tensor for op in tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph().get_operations() for tensor in op.values()]
```

Here I can get the tensors but I can't use the tensors in the model:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=self.tensors[0], outputs=self.tensors[-1])
```

Is there any way to convert this frozen graph to a Keras model?
Or If there is another approach which I can train the model, I would be glad to know.

P.S. The pre-trained model is '*ssd_mobilenet_v3_small_coco_2020_01_14*' which can be found [Here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf1_detection_zoo.md).

Comment: I've added more details about the problem and it's more clear now. If you please reopen the question. Thanks

Comment: Isn't that a [saved model](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model) directory? About using a frozen graph, see if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63619517/1782792) helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can use two methods:

1. The file *'frozen_inference_graph.pb'* contains all necessary information about the weights and the model architecture. Use the following snippet to read the model and add a new layer:a

> ```
>  customModel = tf.keras.models.load_model('savedModel')  
>  # savedModel is the folder with .pb data
>
>  pretrainedOutput = customModel.layers[-1].output 
>  newOutput = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2)(pretrainedOutput) # change layer as needed
>
>  new_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=customModel.inputs, outputs=[newOutput]) 
>  # create a new model with input of old model and new output tensors
> ```

where 'savedModel' is the name of the folder with *'frozen_inference_graph.pb'* and other meta data. See details about using .pb files and finetuning the custom models in the [TFguide](https://cv-tricks.com/tensorflow-tutorial/save-restore-tensorflow-models-quick-complete-tutorial-2-x/).

2. Try using *.meta* file with model architecture and *.ckpt* to restore the weights in TF 1.x:

> ```
> with tf.Session() as sess:
>   new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('my_test_model-1000.meta')
>   new_saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))
> ```

Refer to the [tutorial](https://cv-tricks.com/tensorflow-tutorial/save-restore-tensorflow-models-quick-complete-tutorial/) on how to load and customize restored models in TF 1.x.